# "Virtual Super Resolution"

Tags: debian, gnome, xrandr, monitors, multi-monitor

I am looking to replicate the effect of "[virtual super resolution](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/VSR.aspx)". This seems to be a bit more commonplace in Windows systems (being built right into the Radeon Crimson driver provided by AMD). Being in the Unix/Linux section, I'd like to try and accomplish this on a Linux box. This particular setup has three 1920x1080_60 monitors but I'm only looking to accomplish this feat for a particular monitor (as in, individual settings per monitor).

This particular box is running Debian 9.1 and XRandR 1.5.0. Running on the Radeon driver provided by Xorg. I've ensured that my video card is capable of putting out the resolutions I am attempting to use.

Thus far, I have attempted to create a new mode (and add it to this output) similar to the following:

```
:~$ cvt 2304 1296
# 2304x1296 59.92 Hz (CVT 2.99M9) hsync: 80.53 kHz; pclk: 251.25 MHz
Modeline "2304x1296_60.00"  251.25  2304 2464 2712 3120  1296 1299 1304 1344 -hsync +vsync
:~$ xrandr --newmode "2304x1296_60.00"  251.25  2304 2464 2712 3120  1296 1299 1304 1344 -hsync +vsync
:~$ xrandr --addmode "2304x1296_60.00"
:~$ xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 2304x1296_60.00
```

Unsurprising to many, this didn't work. My monitor complained that the resolution was out of range (big surprise) and I promptly switched it back to the old resolution. I played around with it more but the only thing I accomplished was crashing my X session multiple times. Hooray!

For a more clear example of what I'm trying to accomplish, this is a screen capture of a Windows machine with a 2560x1440_144 capable monitor.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkwpz.jpg

Enabling the "virtual super resolution" option allows me to exceed the resolution that the monitor is capable of. This is a screen capture of the same monitor but scaled to 3200x1800_60.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytrL8.jpg

While writing this, I noticed [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37739/split-a-physical-x-display-into-two-virtual-displays) which (tackled a different problem and) brought up using virtual display devices to accomplish a different effect. **Would either XRandR or virtual displays be a viable option to accomplish what I'm hoping for?**

Note that I am seeking not for a panning screen but an effect similar to that of the first and second screen capture (notice the resolution change on the images). To the video hardware on the Windows system, it is genuinely processing the "super resolution" and not merely changing the scaling. I figure there are some tricks involved and it's not as straightforward as it seems (no one-click option here).

Comment: I doubt it'll work the xrandr. If it's available at all, you'll have to enable it (one of) the Radeon drivers. AFAIK there are several, first step is to figure out (1) which one runs currently (`/var/log/Xorg.log`), (2) if there are alternatives, and (3) read the man pages of them to see if they have this feature.