# Using xrandr to split a display into two virtual screens

Tags: kde, xrandr

From this post [Use xrandr to split display in two virtual screens](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605755/use-xrandr-to-split-display-in-two-virtual-screens?noredirect=1&lq=1), it appears that there were some issues with accomplishing this with common desktop environments.

Has there been any update to this issue? Is the only way via the patch by the user in that post?

I'm particularly interested in doing this on a KDE Debian 10 machine.